# How to instantiate spring bean without being referenced from aop:aspect

Tags: java, spring

Using  Spring and Java;

I have a pointcut which works OK. Now I want to remove the pointcut and AOP from the spring and just trigger the event with an event from inside the java code but I want "myAdvice" bean still called via Spring and its properties set.

I want to get ridoff all advice things even in java code, no more advice or any trace of AOP, I already have a nice event system working. **I just want to instantiate my bean via Spring**.

When I remove the second code block (one starting with "aop:config") then I noticed the bean "myAdvice" is not called and instantiated anymore. How can i stil call it set its properties without referencing it from the "aop:aspect" ?

in my application context ;

```
<bean id="myAdvice" class="com.myclass">
    <property name="name1" ref="ref1" />
    <property name="name2" ref="ref2" />        
</bean>


<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:aspect id="myAspect" ref="myAdvice">
        <aop:pointcut id="myPointcut" expression="execution(* com.myexcmethod" />
        <aop:around pointcut-ref="myPointcut" method="invoke" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Comment: what is `scope="consultation"`? can you remove that?

Comment: And the bean name is `myAdvice` not `myClass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration looks fine  . Your bean should be instantiated as a singleton bean when the ApplicationContext loads up . Maybe you would want to check if you have a default-lazy-init setting which prevents eager loading of the beans.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to get at the bean itself, you can pass it into this function:

```
public static Object unwrapProxy(Object proxiedBean) throws Exception {
    while(proxiedBean instanceof Advised) {
        proxiedBean = ((Advised) proxiedBean).getTargetSource().getTarget();
    }

    return proxiedBean;
}
```

Note that you need to have the loop in order to ensure that you unwrap *all* the AOP advice.

Comment: thanks but I want to get ridoff all advice things even in java code, no more advice or any trace of AOP, I have a nice event system working.I just need to instantiate my bean via spring.